# Laravel post with nodejs MethodNotAllowedHttpException 405 error

Tags: php, node.js, laravel

I use nodejs for the "api" and laravel to post it with an controller. But it gives me an MethodNotAllowedHttpException 405 error while I do so, I'm new to nodejs and want to actually kinda learn it but I want to solve this problem first.

I didn't try a lot cause I don't know actually what I have to different. I searched it on the web tho but none of it helped.

The function in nodejs:

```
    creatFolder() {
        this.auth.allowed('s:version', (allowedErr, isAllowed) => {
            if (allowedErr || !isAllowed) return;

            const uuid = this.auth.server().uuid;

            Fs.access("/srv/daemon-data/" + uuid + "/test", error => {
                if (!error) {

                    this.res.send({"success": "false", "error": "Folder already exists."});

                } else {

                    exec('mkdir /srv/daemon-data/' + uuid + "/test", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
                        if (err) {
                            res.send({"success": "false", "error": "File could not be created!!"});
                        }

                        res.send({"success": "true"});
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

The "route"

```
RestServer.get('/v1/server/test', (req, res, next) => {
    Routes.creatFolder();
    return next();
});
```

The actual api post in laravel controller:

```
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://dev.mrkevko.nl/api/application/servers/51fbca1d/test');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer GKuRPd808MHyqxez9Ph59GG0ql4qqbsAJIZxcRa7E6Rzwmtt';
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'Accept: Application/vnd.pterodactyl.v1+json';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Show your Laravel routes file. A 405 means a method mismatch, such as GET when it should be POST

Comment: `Route::post('/view/{server}/upload/folder', 'ServersController@upload')->name('admin.servers.view.upload.folder');`, I'm sorry for the late response.

Comment: Okay, it's hard to tell who's trying to access what via which route. Can you point that part out? If you're trying to send from nodejs to `/view/{server}/upload/folder` on Laravel, it needs to be a POST request.

Comment: It is an post request.

Comment: Ah, I saw what I did wrong right now. I have editted `RestServer.get` to `RestServer.post`. But it still doesn't work. I also have restarted the node.

Comment: Make sure there's no redirects happening on the Laravel side (ie HTTP -> HTTPS can mess with the method), and watch the logs on both sides to see what's happening.

Comment: I dont do any redirects and I don't see any errors in my logs.